# Prevent applications from overlapping plank

Tags: release-loki, plank

Is there a way to prevent applications from overlapping the plank in normal mode, but also hide the plank if the application goes into full screen mode?

Answer (score 2):

If you hold control and right click on Plank (preferably in an area of the dock itself and not an icon) and go to Preferences > Behavior and select the hide mode you would like. I have mine set to Window Dodge which forces the dock to hide whenever a window tries to overlap - including when it's full screen. That might work for you, but play around with the different settings to find the right one.

Comment: I was using that, but there are times when i close and open certain apps like chrome, and they open a little closer to the bottom of the screen every time. So atm, i am using the option to auto hide when the focused screen is maximized. But this doesn't solve the issue of the windows overlapping the dock when not in full screen, instead, they just appear behind it and i have to move it up. I don't like hiding the dock when a window is not in fullscreen.